# What max Mach number of the blade tips on Concorde's engines?

Tags: jet-engine, concorde

What was the maximum velocity and Mach speed of blade tips in Concorde's engines?

Comment: I'm thinking back then still subsonic. The air inlet was designed to slow down the airflow.

Comment: @mins this does ask what the mach speed is, which the other question doesn't. Subtle difference but still a difference.

Comment: @mins I’ve edited the question, thoughts?

Comment: @Notts90: I personally rejected your edit as it clearly modifies the initial question (and the possible answers). Now the question has been changed, I see that it's still covered by [the same post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/34959/3201). I'd prefer better answers to be added to the first question rather than being split between two questions.

Comment: @mins Did either of the two answers to the other question compute the relative speed at the tip of the first compressor rotor?

Comment: @jjack: The linear speed of the blade is available in plain sight (340 m/s, which at sea level is exactly M 1) and results from a trivial multiplication of the perimeter by the angular speed. The bonus is the axial airspeed provided in the second answer (M .49). What does prevent you to read? Now there is a bit of [velocity triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_triangle) calculation to be done in a better answer. Note that 'duplicate' doesn't refer to answers but to the questions themselves, whatever the answers currently are.

Comment: @mins I'm asking myself what prevents you from simply calculating right: angular speed is in [rad/s], the circumference is 2pi * radius. The post gives [rpm] though. RPM is not angular speed, it's also in minutes and you should be 2pi too large doing it your way.